# Setting up Password Free SSH from Linux to Windows 10

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to set up a password free ssh path from a linux server to a windows machine. I currently have MobaSSH running on the windows machine. I can ssh from the linux server to the windows machine fine and execute commands just fine but I have to enter a password.

I create a public RSA key on the linux system and using WinSCP I copied the file over to the C:\Users\MyUserName\.ssh folder and restarted the MobaSSh service on the windows machine.

It still won't let me ssh in without a password. What am I missing here? Any help vastly appreciated.

Comment: Whatever `.pub` key was generated on the linux system, should be renamed to `authorized_keys` which then belongs in `C:\Users\MyUserName\.ssh`  Did you definately rename it to `authorized_keys` ?

Comment: I did forget that step. So I copied the public rsa key to authorized_keys in C:\Users\MyUserName\.ssh. I rebooted and restarted everything and still it asks for a password. I created the public rsa key on the linux machine and copied to the windows machine, that should be correct. Not sure what else I'm missing here.

Comment: Do you have filename extensions for known file types visible in windows.  To be certain that `authorized_keys` hasn't retained the `.pub` extension.

Comment: Yes, I always keep my file extensions visible. It''s an old but good habit. No file extensions on 'authorized_keys'

Comment: Can you edit the question with your actual `sshd_config` file from the windows box or a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) of that?  Specifically what's the line `PubkeyAuthentication` look like?

Answer (score 3):

OpenSSH is available for Windows 10 and has worked very reliably for me. I can consistently connect from a Linux machine without a password. Here is how to set it up.

- upgrade to Windows 10 version 1809 or higher

  - check via: `powershell -c "(Get-Item 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion').GetValue('ReleaseID')"`; see also `systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"` for Pro vs. Home, build number
  - upgrade via Windows Update settings or [Download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) (the latter works around an issue where some systems are [stuck at 1803](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/c3anuk/still_on_1803_and_check_for_updates_still_not/))
- install SSH client and server (as administrator; [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)) - **in Windows PowerShell**:

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
Start-Service sshd  # remote login should be possible following this command
Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'
Get-NetFirewallRule -Name *ssh*  # there should be a firewall rule named "OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP"  # optional
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0  # optional
```

- enabling public key login for administrators ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/connect-your-device/ssh)) - **from Linux command-line**:

```
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub administrator@remote_computer_name:'C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys'  # if using an alternate method, ensure file is not UTF-16 encoded
icacls C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys /remove "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users"
icacls C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys /inheritance:r
get-acl C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host_dsa_key | set-acl C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys
```

- enabling public key login for non-administrators - **in Windows PowerShell**:

```
Install-Module -Force OpenSSHUtils -Scope AllUsers  # for: Repair-AuthorizedKeyPermission
cd C:\Users\...
ssh-keygen  # create ~/.ssh
# add key(s) to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ConfirmPreference = 'None'; Repair-AuthorizedKeyPermission -FilePath .ssh\authorized_keys
# if above fails, try ''%%Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser%%''; see also https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1245#issuecomment-440388604
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot. I looked in regedit and my windows 10 version is 1703 so I'm upgrading now, thanks for the link! I'll keep everyone posted.

Comment: This answers doesn't work (anymore): "Repair-AuthorizedKeyPermission" doesn't exist, neither does 'OpenSSHUtils'. See -> https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/pull/4788#issuecomment-687662994